# ¿Cómo mostrar diagramas de plantuml sin instalar graphviz?

Tags: plantuml

Como algunos saben plantuml muchas veces requiere de la herramienta [graphviz](/questions/tagged/graphviz) para pintar algunos diagramas como el diagrama de clases.

¿Cómo puedo pintar aquellas cosas que no me deja si no tengo instalado graphviz o por alguna razón no lo puedo instalar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para modificar esto hay un comando especial con la siguiente sintaxis:

```
!pragma graphviz_dot <nombre_del_programa_remplazo>
```

Un muy buen programa de remplazo que yo he usado con IntelliJ Idea y que no requiere instalar nada es jdot.

Para ello agrega a tu diagrama la línea y luego el código de tu diagrama como lo haces normalmente

```
@startuml
!pragma graphviz_dot jdot
class Animal
class Gato
class Perro
Animal <|-- Gato
Animal <|-- Perro
@enduml
```

Fuentes:

- https://docs-as-co.de/news/plantuml-without-graphviz/
- https://plantuml.com/es/smetana02